# Creating subfolders in ArcPy's 'in_memory'

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, in-memory

Is there a way to create a subfolder in memory in ArcPy?

For example, instead of temporarily saving a dataset under:

```
r'in_memory/bufferOne'
```

I would like to save it under:

```
r'in_memory/buffers/bufferOne'
```

This spits out an error message, of course. But is there a way to still achieve the same effect?

Background: I am working on a tool that create **a lot** of intermediate data that does not need to be saved. Right now I am saving each intermediate output into separate folders, which makes it easier to check out the outputs during testing, and it avoids the annoyance of filtering when using things like **arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()** (that is actually the number one reason for using all these subfolders):

[image]

Now that I know that I am getting the correct results I would like to save most of these steps *in_memory*, to speed up the tool. It would be ideal if I could just adopt this structure and change a few paths in my script instead of adding a lot of filter logic.

Comment: why not simply write your path with an "_" if you want a track of the structure ? in_memory/buffer_bufferone

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! So simple, yet I would not have thought of it! You should post this as an answer, so I can mark it.

Comment: Or create python lists of feature classes you want lumped together as you work with them... `a_firstBuff = [fc1, fc12, fc25]`, etc.

Comment: I did this before but I ran into an issue at some point; cannot remember why. But I read today that appending to a list can be exhaustive when used in a loop with big datasets. I am trying to keep as much out of my loops as possible, as Arc is already having trouble with my script.

Answer (score 5):

No - in_memory workspaces are only similar to and not identical to geodatabase workspaces. They support feature classes but not feature datasets.

This is documented on the [Using in-memory workspace](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/the-in-memory-workspace.htm) help page:

> Feature datasets or folders cannot be created in the in-memory
>   workspace.